# How can i do a check for nulls in a lambda expression in c#?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following but some of the fields are null and causes an error:

```
  Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: source
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)


foreach (var value in users.entries.Where(x => (x.field1 || x.field2 || x.field3) && 
       !x.field4 && !x.field5))                   
 {
   //code 
 }
```

How can i do a check for nulls in the following expression , so check for the fields ,
field1,field2, field3,field4,field5  ?

Answer (score 0):

looking from the error its likely your `users.entries` was null so you could not call `Where` on it.

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: source

Here `source` is the first parameter of the `Where(...)` extension

try this

```cs
if (users?.entries is null) {
  // handle null
}
else  {

   foreach ...
}
```